# Unable to start DSE, getting "Class not found: org/apache/lucene/uninverting/FieldCache"

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise

DSE server Version : 6.8
Followed installation steps as per the datastax documentation (Tar file installation)

Startup command: bin/dse cassandra -s (Needs search featire , so enabled solr as well)

Error while executing start command:

```
WARN  [main] 2022-03-01 19:05:59,855  DatabaseDescriptor.java:1531 - JMX is not enabled to receive remote connections. Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info.
INFO  [main] 2022-03-01 19:05:59,857  DseDelegateSnitch.java:39 - Setting my workloads to [Cassandra, Search]
INFO  [main] 2022-03-01 19:05:59,904  YamlConfigurationLoader.java:77 - Configuration location: file:/Users/rajamani/repositories/cassandra/dse-6.8.20/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  [main] 2022-03-01 19:05:59,912  DseDelegateSnitch.java:41 - Initialized DseDelegateSnitch with workloads [Cassandra, Search], delegating to com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseSimpleSnitch
INFO  [main] 2022-03-01 19:06:00,049  YamlConfigurationLoader.java:77 - Configuration location: file:/Users/rajamani/repositories/cassandra/dse-6.8.20/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  [main] 2022-03-01 19:06:01,154  AuthConfig.java:125 - System keyspaces filtering not enabled.
INFO  [main] 2022-03-01 19:06:01,155  IAuditLogger.java:136 - Audit logging is disabled
WARN  [main] 2022-03-01 19:06:01,215  DisabledTPCBackpressureController.java:20 - TPC backpressure is disabled. NOT RECOMMENDED.
INFO  [main] 2022-03-01 19:06:01,216  TPC.java:137 - Created 9 NIO event loops (with I/O ratio set to 50).
INFO  [main] 2022-03-01 19:06:01,239  TPC.java:144 - Created 1 TPC timers due to configured ratio of 5.
INFO  [main] 2022-03-01 19:06:01,524  DseConfig.java:372 - CQL slow log is enabled
INFO  [main] 2022-03-01 19:06:01,526  DseConfig.java:373 - CQL system info tables are not enabled
INFO  [main] 2022-03-01 19:06:01,526  DseConfig.java:374 - Resource level latency tracking is not enabled
INFO  [main] 2022-03-01 19:06:01,526  DseConfig.java:375 - Database summary stats are not enabled
INFO  [main] 2022-03-01 19:06:01,526  DseConfig.java:376 - Cluster summary stats are not enabled
INFO  [main] 2022-03-01 19:06:01,526  DseConfig.java:377 - Histogram data tables are not enabled
INFO  [main] 2022-03-01 19:06:01,528  DseConfig.java:378 - User level latency tracking is not enabled
INFO  [main] 2022-03-01 19:06:01,529  DseConfig.java:380 - Spark cluster info tables are not enabled
INFO  [main] 2022-03-01 19:06:01,531  DseConfig.java:420 - Cql solr query paging is: off
INFO  [main] 2022-03-01 19:06:01,535  DseUtil.java:324 - /proc/cpuinfo is not available, defaulting to 1 thread per CPU core...
INFO  [main] 2022-03-01 19:06:01,536  DseConfig.java:424 - This instance appears to have 1 thread per CPU core and 10 total CPU threads.
INFO  [main] 2022-03-01 19:06:01,538  DseConfig.java:441 - Server ID:F4-D4-88-66-17-8D
ERROR [main] 2022-03-01 19:06:02,024  DseModule.java:114 - Class not found: org/apache/lucene/uninverting/FieldCache. Exiting...
```

This particular class exists as part of solr-core.
does DSE-server does not have solr bundle ? (Even after placing the lib under solr lib, this particulat error occurs.

Can you please assist to resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is most likely a symptom of another problem. For example, it's quite common to get "class not found" exceptions when using Java 11 with Cassandra. DataStax Enterprise 6.8 is compatible with Cassandra 3.11 which only supports Java 8.

For what it's worth, [Java 11 support was only added to Cassandra 4.0](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0.2/CHANGES.txt#L2) ([CASSANDRA-16894](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16894)). Older versions of Cassandra only work with Java 8.

Going back to your original question, we need a bit more information to investigate the issue but our ability to help you in a Q&A forum is limited. Please log a ticket with [DataStax Support](https://support.datastax.com/) and one of our engineers will advise you on what diagnostic info is required and the next steps. Cheers!

Comment: Got worked with Java 11 and server started. Thanks